# How do I get a static route in a Phoenix live view?

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework, phoenix-live-view

In my live view template I added this snippet:

```
  <script src="<%= Routes.static_path(@socket, "/js/hi.js") %>"></script>
```

That produced the following error:
[image]

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 2):

I got it working by replacing

```
  use Phoenix.LiveView
```

with

```
  use MyAppWeb, :live_view
```

in watch_live.ex.

Comment: `Routes` is just an alias for `MyAppWeb.Router.Helpers`. You could have kept `use Phoenix.LiveView` and changed `Routes` to `MyAppWeb.Router.Helpers`. You can see this alias in the `def view` block in your `my_app_web.ex` file.